# Converting Datasets and Shared Datasets to t-sql stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to automatically generate stored procedures out of the t-sql in the datasets found in an ssrs project?

Comment: What?  What does data have to do with executable SQL?

Comment: Not sure I`m clear. Looking for a way to transfer the t-sql code from a dataset to create a new stored procedure with that code. I need to convert datasets to use stored procedures only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an automatic way to do this. You might be able to cobble something together to do it though. SSRS reports are in an XML format. The Datasets are in a **< DataSets >** element.

Unfortunately, I don't know how helpful it would be since the parameters would need to be resolved.

Someone created a **Powershell** to retrieve the dataset definitions from a report if you want to try to automate something. I think it would still need manual work to convert them - especially if they use parameters or have calculated fields.

https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/94491/retrieve-dataset-definitions-from-ssrs-report.html